# Synonym for “Small but Obvious”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, synonyms

I’ve seen many works in which the phrase “small but obvious” is used. I understand and acknowledge the fact that it is, essentially, perfectly fine to simply use these precise words; however, I was wondering if there was a single word which accurately sums up the meaning of the phrase. I could swear that I’ve heard a term like it before, but I cannot for the life of me remember what it was.

I’ve already done a quick search on Google, but the entire first page of engine results were—primarily—synonyms and definitions of both “obvious” and “non-obvious”, through *six* links to online thesauri and dictionaries, respectively.

The other four referred me to online books, via Google Books; *Systema Porifera: A Guide to the Classification of Sponges*, *Mammals of South America, Volume 2: Rodents*, *Vascular Flora of the Southeastern United States: Asteraceae*, and *The Proterozoic Biosphere: A Multidisciplinary Study*.

. . . I’ve decided that I’ll most likely be best off in the long run if I simply avoid the content suggestions on the next pages.

Anyway! Just in case a provided example would make answering this easier, then this is the context in which I’m going to use it:

> His breathing quickened, a [*small yet obvious*] change that hadn’t gone unnoticed by his friend.

Any feedback is appreciated, and comments are always welcome! Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: Can you use understated or distinctive?

Comment: This is getting into the 'deceptively spacious' realms of realtors/estate agents.

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised that you see *small but obvious* (or *small yet obvious*) often. What's the context?

Comment: What an odd comment. Where exactly have you seen this phrase: small but obvious?? I just think if you are writing, you have to find it yourself.

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, that's what I was trying to say too. (Which comment did you think was odd?)

Comment: @Drew I think we agree. To say you have seen "many works" with ""small but obvious" in the text just does  not ring true. I am sure I have read hundreds if not thousands of books where all sorts of things are repeated. It is not a set phrase, it is not a cliche, it is not a standard image. It's an undoable question. I call them these question TTP.  This is a writer fishing for ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is **subtle**. With a slight modification to the original sentence to account for the contradiction in meaning (i.e. that it was both a slight and noticeable change), the term will do just fine.

Definition (Google):

> (especially of a change or distinction) so delicate or precise as to be difficult to analyze or describe

Here's how I would rephrase your sentence:

> His breathing quickened. Though it was a subtle change, it did not elude his observant friend.

Notice the addition of "though" compensates for the apparent contradiction that a keen reader would otherwise spot. Additionally, the characterization of his friend as one who is "observant" further clarifies your meaning.

I realize the term does not exactly fit your requisite, but to be fair, I don't think such a word exists (though I could be wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your insight; it’s very appreciated. This wasn’t *quite* what I’d had in mind—I’d already considered using *subtle*, though I eventually decided against it because I wasn’t entirely sure how to rephrase the sentence—but your suggestion was incredibly helpful. I’m curious, though, as to whether this was something that you came across via internet or a book (and, if so, may you reference the medium in which you found this?), or if this was something that you rephrased using your own words?

Comment: I rephrased it using my own words :) Glad you found it helpful

Answer (score 1):

Although its meaning is "small but valuable", perhaps 'modicum' would work.

See [modicum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modicum) at **Oxford dictionary**, defined as

> A small quantity of a particular thing, especially something desirable or valuable

Comment: Can you find a dictionary giving a definition where 'a modicum of a spot [on his knee]' is licensed for a small but obvious spot?

Comment: No! But its all I've got.

Comment: As tchrist has said, [On ELU] we are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers. // The problem is, people may see an 'answer' here and take it as authoritative. When it isn't.

Comment: I am humbled -- I thought 'valuable' might replace 'obvious' in the given context, and "quantum" no longer seems suitable.

Comment: More documented answers for a question like this? Harumph.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of [***perceptible***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/perceptible). From Oxford Dictionaries:

> ADJECTIVE (especially of a slight movement or change of state) able to be seen or noticed.

I think the implication of a ***slight*** movement or change of state might match what you mean by "small" and *able to be seen or noticed* is fairly close to "obvious" The adverb *barely* is often included for even tinier movements. So for your example:

> His breathing quickened, a **(barely) perceptible** change that hadn’t gone unnoticed by his friend.